# Smoothly invertible additive/subtractive luminance blending in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, alphablending, blending, pyopengl

I'm trying to perform a rather specific blending operation, but one that seems like it ought to be relatively simple. I'm displaying a luminance texture on top of a background with an alpha value of one.

For example, this could be a simple checkerboard on top of another image:

[image]

I want the texture to linearly increment/decrement the luminance of the background according to:

```
(R_b + R_t * w, G_b + G_t * w, B_b + B_t * w, 1.0)
```

where `*_b` are the background pixel values (between 0 and 1), `*_t` are signed pixel values for the overlaid texture (between -1 and 1), and `w` is a weighting parameter that can also vary between -1 and 1. The goal is that by varying the sign and magnitude of `w` I can smoothly vary the magnitude and polarity of the modulation of the background by the checkerboard texture.

To give you a graphical example:

[image]

Using `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` and just varying the alpha value of my overlay won't quite do what I want, because I can't use negative alpha values to invert the polarity of my overlay.

Is there a way to do this type of linear additive/subtractive blending using the fixed pipeline, or failing that, would it be possible to implement this using a shader?

### Update

For further clarification I've added a crude PyOpenGL example of what I'm trying to do [here](https://gist.github.com/alimuldal/77b47f58109e6d2de35d).

### Update 2

To be totally clear, if `w > 0`, I want to *increase* the luminance of every pixel within a *white* squares on my checkerboard, and *decrease* the luminance of every pixel within a *black* square. If `w < 0` I want to do the opposite.

**derhass**'s answer comes very close to what I'm looking for, but only affects the pixels in the white squares and not the black squares:

[image]

Humans are terrible at judging absolute luminance, but the difference is clearer if I set the color of the overlay to red (`glColor4f(1., 0., 0., 0.25)`):

[image]

As you can see, this results in adding/subtracting red from the white squares, but does not change the black squares.

Comment: What version of GL are you targeting? Luminance textures are no longer supported (3.1+ non-compatibility). You could either (rather hackishly) use a depth texture to get a single-component texture where `r`,`g`,`b` have the same value and `a` is constant **1.0** or use `GL_RED` (`g` and `b` will be undefined and `a` will be **1.0**).

Comment: Since you talk about wanting signed colors, I would rule out the depth texture. You might need `GL_R8_SNORM` and some swizzling (whether it be the extension or in an actual shader).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman To give you some context, this code is part of a fairly esoteric bit of scientific software written in PyOpenGL that is already riddled with legacy OGL API calls, so I'm not particularly concerned that `GL_LUMINANCE` is now deprecated. I don't specifically require signed colors - what I'm after is a single blending mode that will allow me to modulate the luminance of a background image both additively and subtractively.

Comment: That's precisely while programmable pipeline has been introduced.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm definitely open to the idea of using a shader for this, but I got the impression that it wasn't possible since blending is what is done with the output of the fragment shader.

Comment: @ali_m it's entirely possible to render to texture and then compose the images manually, though.

Comment: @ali_m: You wouldn't use blending. The most straightforward approach is that you bind the two textures to two different texture units, sample both textures in your fragment shader, and combine the values with any mathematical formula your heart desires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use GL's blending as long as your `w` parameter will not vary per pixel, but is just global to the whole draw call of the overlay texture (as your images also suggest). You just need to set up the blend equation depending on the sign of `w`:

Set the Blend factors to `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE)`, and

- For w>=0: use [`glBlendEquation`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBlendEquation.xml)`(GL_FUNC_ADD)` and set alpha to w
- For w<0: use [`glBlendEquation`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBlendEquation.xml)`(GL_FUNC_REVERSE_SUBTRACT)` and set alpha to -w

As described so far, this will also modify the alpha component of the output, but you want that to be 1.0. As you said, your frambeuffer has already alpha=1 when you render the background. So you can just use [`glBlendFuncSeparate`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBlendFuncSeparate.xml)`(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE,GL_ZERO,GL_ONE)` which in conjunction with the above equations will set the resulting alpha to that of the destination, `A_b` in your notation.

### UPDATE

It turned out that the formula in the question is not the desired behavior, and the assumption that only the `GL_FUNC_ADD` *or* `GL_FUNC_REVERSE_SUBTRACT` is required per draw call does not hold.

However, it is possible to use negative alpha values, if a *floating point* color buffer is used ([`ARB_color_buffer_float`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/color_buffer_float.txt)).

> If the color buffer is fixed-point, the components of the source and
>   destination values and blend factors are each clamped to [0; 1] or
>   [-1; 1] respectively for an unsigned normalized or signed normalized
>   color buffer prior to evaluating the blend equation. If the color
>   buffer is floating-point, no clamping occurs. The resulting four
>   values are sent to the next operation.

Note that this extension introduces the [`glClampColor()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glClampColor.xml) function and defines the targets `GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR`, `GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR` and `GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR`. The latter two are deprecated in modern GL and relevant only for the deprecated fixed function pipeline.

Comment: That *looks* almost right, but it doesn't quite solve my problem. With `glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD)`, the luminance in the regions under the 'bright' squares in the checkerboard gets incremented (which is good), but the 'dark' squares do not get decremented. Similarly, with `glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_REVERSE_SUBTRACT)` the 'bright' squares get decremented (which is also good), but again the 'dark' squares are unmodified. Is that clear enough? I'll try and add a little bit more explanation to my question.

Comment: @ali_m: well, it _exactly_ models the formula you have given. And the formula seems not just to be what you want: in the Black squares, your X_t values are all zero, and according to your formula, this will lead just to the destination value beeing kept as it is. _Maybe_ you just want `glBendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` but that is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, you're right - that's entirely my fault! I had envisaged using something like a `GL_RGB_SNORM` texture signed values between 1 and -1, which would allow me to simultaneously increment and decrement pixel values (I think Andon's comment was alluding to this).

Comment: @ali_m: OK, so in this case, you probably can still use the blending in conjunction with a floating-point framebuffer (see section 4.1.8 (Blending) of the [`GL_ARB_color_buffer_float` spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/color_buffer_float.txt)) which basically allows you to use negative alpha values. You will probably need another render pass to convert the results into standrad UNORM data which can be displayed, though.

Comment: Nice - that seems to do the trick! In my real code I was already rendering to a framebuffer, so it was simply a matter of changing the framebuffer color attachment to a float format, and turning off clamping with the `glClampColor()` functions.

Comment: If you put something to that effect in your answer then I'd be happy to accept it. Cheers!